# Gordon Growth Model (2-Step) Approximation

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, finance

It is easy to prove that the sum of the infinite geometric series $$\frac{D(1+g)^n}{(1+r)^n}$$ is $$S = \frac{D(1+g)}{r-g}$$ where n = 1, 2, 3, ... and 0 < g < r < 1.

Now, if the infinite series becomes:

$$\frac{D(1+g_0)^n}{(1+r)^n},  n = 1, 2, ... , A$$

$$\frac{D(1+g_0)^A(1+g_1)^{n-A}}{(1+r)^n}, n = A+1, A+2, ...$$

Show that the sum approximates the following (assume $0< g_1 < g_0 < r < 1$):

$$S = \frac{D}{r-g_1}[(1+g_1) + A(g_0-g_1)]$$

Comment: Yes. Please see the 1984 paper by Fuller and Hsia: A Simplified Common Stock Valuation Model. I was interested in how they derived equation 6 and 7 in that paper. Please help!

Comment: The sum is actually a present value (PV) of discounted dividends (D). I use S to denote the sum since it is a sum. The authors used P for price or present value. Sorry about the confusion and feel free to use either notation for the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: area under the curves]

I have figured out graphically and suspect that the authors did so similarly.

We are basically trying to approximate the area under the solid blue and black curves (leaving out the discounting by $(1+r)^n$ first, hence the exponential growth).

This area is approximately the same as (a bit smaller than) the area under the blue curve (solid and dashed). To calculate that area, we need to figure out the value at which the blue curve intersects the vertical axis.

Since we already know the value at which the black curve intersects the vertical axis: $D(1+g_0)$, we just need to calculate the gap as marked on the graph. The gap is approximately the difference between $a_A$ and $a_A^*$ if $a_1$ had grown at $g_1$. Then

$$Gap = \frac{D(1+g_0)^A}{(1+g_1)^A}$$

Linear approximation gives:

$$Gap = D[(1 + Ag_0) - (1 + Ag_1)] = DA(g_0 - g_1)$$

Going back to the Gordon Growth Model, all the calculation we just did were for the purpose of adjusting the numerator, which corresponds to the vertical axis intersect on our graph.

Voila! The numerator is now approximated as $D(1+g_0) + DA(g_0 - g_1)$

Finally we have the approximation of $S$:

$$\frac{D[(1 + g_0) + A(g_0 - g_1)]}{r - g_1}$$

Answer (score 3):

For the infinite geometric series $\frac{D(1+g)^n}{(1+r)^n},0<g<r<1$, the sum is indeed:
$$S=\frac{\frac{D(1+g)}{1+r}}{1-\frac{1+g}{1+r}}=\frac{D(1+g)}{r-g}.$$
Reference: [Gordon growth model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividend_discount_model).

**1-method:** The sum of $A$ terms:
$$S_A=\frac{\frac{D(1+g_0)}{1+r}\cdot \left(1-\left(\frac{1+g_0}{1+r}\right)^A\right)}{1-\frac{1+g_0}{1+r}}=\frac{D(1+g_0)[(1+r)^A-(1+g_0)^A]}{(r-g_0)(1+r)^A}$$
The sum of the remaining infinite terms (from $(A+1)$ to infinity) is:
$$S_{A^*}=\frac{\frac{D(1+g_0)^A(1+g_1)}{(1+r)^{A+1}}}{1-\frac{1+g_1}{1+r}}=\frac{D(1+g_0)^A(1+g_1)}{(r-g_1)(1+r)^A}$$
Now add $S_A$ and $S_{A^*}$ and approximate to get $S$.

---

**Update: 2-method:**
Refer to the fragment from the referrenced article:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

---

First, note that it should be denoted by $P$ not $S$, because it is a present (not future) value of a stock. Second, note that $g_a=g_0, g_n=g_1, D_A=D_0(1+g_a)^A$. So, derivation of $6$:

$$\text{PV(Step 1)}=D_0\sum_{t=1}^A\left(\frac{1+g_a}{1+r}\right)^t=D_0\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1+g_a}{1+r}\right)^t-D_0\sum_{t=A+1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1+g_a}{1+r}\right)^t=\\
\frac{D_0(1+g_a)}{r-g_a}-D_0\cdot \frac{\frac{(1+g_a)^{A+1}}{(1+r)^{A+1}}}{1-\frac{1+g_a}{1+r}}=\frac{D_0(1+g_a)}{r-g_a}\cdot \left[1-\frac{(1+g_a)^A}{(1+r)^A}{}\right];\\
\text{PV(Step 2)}=\frac{\frac{D_0(1+g_a)^A(1+g_n)}{(1+r)^{A+1}}}{1-\frac{1+g_n}{1+r}}=\frac{D_0(1+g_a)^A(1+g_n)}{(r-g_n)(1+r)^A};\\
\text{PV(Step 1)+PV(Step 2)}=\frac{D_0(1+g_a)}{r-g_a}\cdot \left[1-\frac{(1+g_a)^A}{(1+r)^A}+\frac{(1+g_a)^{A-1}(1+g_n)(r-g_a)}{(r-g_n)(1+r)^A}\right]=\\
\frac{D_0(1+g_a)}{r-g_a}\cdot \left[1-\frac{(1+g_a)^{A-1}[(1+g_a)(r-g_n)-(1+g_n)(r-g_a)]}{(r-g_n)(1+r)^A}\right]=\\
\frac{D_0(1+g_a)}{r-g_a}\cdot \left[1-\frac{(1+g_a)^{A-1}[\require{cancel}\cancel{r}+g_ar-g_n-\cancel{g_ag_n}-\cancel{r}-g_nr+g_a+\cancel{g_ag_n}]}{(r-g_n)(1+r)^A}\right]=\\
\frac{D_0(1+g_a)}{r-g_a}\cdot \left[1-\left(\frac{1+g_a}{1+r}\right)^{A-1}\cdot \frac{g_a-g_n}{r-g_n}\right].$$

However, next fragment shows the derivation of $7$ is concealed:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but I was asking for the detailed steps for approximating $S_A + S_{A^*}$ to S

Comment: Thanks for the derivation of 6! For the derivation of 7, I have ventured a try below and suspect that it really is not directly related to 6. The authors showed 6 and 7 in sequence, misleading us to think that 7 is derived straight from 6. But still, I was wondering about the derivation of 6 too, so many thanks!